# Need help with converting sentence to predicate logic

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm trying to write a predicate logic for this statement but I'm not sure if I'm writing this correctly. Can anyone validate and let me know if this is correct and if not, help to come up with the correct syntax, please. Thanks in advance.

∀x (P(x) (A(x) ^ (H(x)) -----> Accumulation(bad cholesterol(x))

Lack of physical activity and high calorie diet can lead to accumulation of bad cholesterol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea:
First, translate the information into predicates. 
Let $A(x)$ be physical activity, $B(x)$ be high calories and $C(x)$ be accumulation of cholesterol. You want to say for every $x$ if  $\neg A(x) \land B(x)$ are satisfied, $C(x)$ is as well. That is:
$$ \forall x, [(\neg A(x) \land B(x)) \rightarrow C(x)]
$$

We can interpret this as saying, "for every entity $x$, if $x$ lacks physical activity and has a high calorie diet, then $x$ will accumulate cholesterol."

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. How would I translate this results?

Comment: translate to what?

Comment: Would this reads like this: For every entity x, if x lack physical activity and high calorie diet, then x can lead to accumulation of cholesterol.

Comment: I wouldn't say $x$ leads to accumulation, because then it sounds like $x$ is causing the accumulation. I'd say  "For every entity $x$, if $x$ lacks physical activity and has a high calorie diet, then $x$ will accumulate cholesterol.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!

Comment: @Evan, don't ask for an accept vote for your answer less than one-half hour of the question has been posted, and only 15 minutes after posting your answer.